# Reduce Data set to contain files with only certain qualities

Tags: python, dataset, gaussian, reduction

I just have a quick question about data reduction. I have about 1500 files and I want to delete the ones which don't meet a certain criteria.

Basically I am fitting gaussians to the data set, which gives me a mean and a full width half max. I want to select only the files which give a curve with a mean around +/- 1500 and a full width half max of less than 5000.

I was planning to use an if condition, but it's proving more difficult than I first thought.

What I have so far:

```
if FWHM <= 5000 and (-1600 <= mean <= -1500):
   return (send data to plotting function)
elif FWHM <= 5000 and (1500 <= mean <= 1600):
   return (send data to plotting function)
else:
   os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
```

This doesn't seem to be working, and I think it probably isn't the best way either.

Any tips? Much appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry I should clarify. I want the files which contain a mean either in the range -1600 to -1500 OR 1500 to 1600. The idea later on will be to superimpose these on each other and determine whether they are mirror opposites. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be working" mean, exactly?  The code looks very straightforward, and it's a good bet that it's doing exactly what you told it to do ;-)

Comment: It seems to just be sending everything to the plotting function and then deleting it anyway, whether it meets the criteria or not.

Comment: Hmm.  The code you posted here would not do that.  No way.  In fact, while it could be simplified a little, the code you posted should do almost exactly what you said you wanted it to do (with trivial differences - for example, you said "full width half max of less than 5000", but the code uses `<=` instead of `<` - doesn't matter at all).

Comment: When the condition is met the function returns, when it is not met an action is taken but it does not return.  Without seeing more of the code it seems that if you are done with that file when the condition is met then you should be done with it when it is not met. Am i looking at it correctly?

Comment: Ok I fixed it. It turns out my parameters (particularly the FWHM) were a little tight so it was removing all the files. Thanks for the reassurance though, I was starting to doubt my competency with python :s.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
FWHM <= 5000 and (-1500 <= mean <= 1500)
```

Your if structure will only be true if mean is between -1600 and -1500 or between 1500 and 1600 but not anywhere in -1500 to 1500 which is exactly what you want, i.e., it will never work =).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify with abs(), having less statements might help with the diagnosis.  Maybe print out all the good files that are also deleted - to ensure what is happening is what you believe is happening.

```
if FWHM <= 5000 and (1500 <= abs(mean) <= 1600):
   true_file = os.path.join(path, f)
   return (send data to plotting function)
else:
   if true_file == os.path.join(path, f):
       print 'I am deleting a GOOD file:', true_file
   os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
   true_file = ''
```

edit to add diagnostic print statement

Comment: Thanks, adding the print statement made a big difference in helping me identify the issue (i.e. my parameters were too tight).